# JAXB xjc parsing fails when -binding is used together with -catalog (bug?)

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

Below is the absolute trivial, minimal example that demonstrates the problem.
Three schema files: *A.xsd*, *B.xsd*, *C.xsd* in the following import configuration:

```
C.xsd ---------------- imports ----------------> A.xsd
  \                                          /  
   \---- imports ---> B.xsd --- imports ----/
```

So *A.xsd* is imported directly by *C.xsd* and again indirectly through *B.xsd*. The problem occurs when trying to run **xjc** (ver. **2.2.4**) on *C.xsd* when **both** a catalog **and** a binding file is used (even an empty one).

### A.xsd

```
<schema targetNamespace="foo://a"
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <simpleType name="year">
      <restriction base="dateTime">
         <pattern value="\d{4}"/>
      </restriction>
   </simpleType>
</schema>
```

### B.xsd

```
<schema targetNamespace="foo://b"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <import namespace="foo://a" schemaLocation="boo://a.xsd"/>
</schema>
```

### C.xsd

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="foo://c">
  <import namespace="foo://a" schemaLocation="A.xsd"/>
  <import namespace="foo://b" schemaLocation="B.xsd"/>
</schema>
```

### catalog.xml

```
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog"> 
    <system systemId="boo://a.xsd"  uri="A.xsd"/>
</catalog>
```

### binding.xjb

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1"/>
```

Given the above files, all placed in the same directory the below invocation succeeds:

```
xjc -d src -extension -catalog catalog.xml C.xsd
```

whereas the following invocation:

```
xjc -d src -extension -catalog catalog.xml C.xsd -b bindings.xjb
```

... **fails** with the bug-like message (pointing to some internal mess-up?):

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] 'year' is already defined
  line 8 of file:/home/brutus/A.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 3 of file:/home/brutus/A.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

### UPDATE

Posted a [bug report](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-963).

Answer (score 1):

I ran your example using the XJC that comes with JDK 1.7.0_21-b12 for the Mac, and it worked fine.  You should just need to switch not a newer version of XJC from the JAXB reference implmeentation (see: https://jaxb.java.net/) to get your use case to work.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/10/jaxb-xjc-imported-schemas-and-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar if not the same issue. Could you find any workaround? Tested with `jaxb-ri-2.2.7`, `xjc 2.2.4-2 (OpenJDK 7u25)` and `jaxb-ri-2.2.1.1-4 of GlassFish`.

The most interesting thing is that when using an import without a schemaLocation in combination with a `public` catalog entry everything works. Unfortunately I am not able to adjust the schemas.

Here's a little example.

Failing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:test="http://www.test.com/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd"/>

    <element name="TestElement" type="test:TestType"/>
    <complexType name="TestType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="name" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
        <attribute ref="xlink:title" use="required"/>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:test="http://www.test.com/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>

    <element name="TestElement" type="test:TestType"/>
    <complexType name="TestType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="name" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
        <attribute ref="xlink:title" use="required"/>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Catalog file (for both):

```
<!DOCTYPE catalog
    PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN"
           "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">

    <system
        systemId="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd"
        uri="../schemas/xlink/1.0.0/xlinks.xsd"/>
    <public
        publicId="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        uri="../schemas/xlink/1.0.0/xlinks.xsd"/>

</catalog>
```

Execution (for both):

`xjc schemas/xlink/1.0.0/xlinks.xsd schemas/test.xsd -b xjb/xlink.xjb -extension -d .build -catalog catalog/catalog.xml`

Comment: Couldn't find any workaround, ditched JAXB and work directly with XML using xpath. Tools are always more solid one level below.