# SOAP web services in Java without JAXB / JAX-WS WSDL code generation

Tags: soap, jax-ws, xjc, wsimport

Are there any resources / libraries I should look into if trying to implement client and server side components for a SOAP web service in Java (defined in WSDL) but **not** wishing to use the WSDL/JAXB-based code generation for client and server stubs?

For the record, the reason I am trying to eschew `wsimport` for stub generation is that both `wsimport` and `xjc` fail to properly generate Java code for the schema files I have to use - which are numerous and rather complex - and despite using episodic compilation I still hit what may likely be bugs in JAXB code generation logic (e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274109/jaxb-compiler-was-unable-to-honor-this-schemabinding-customization) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055533/jaxb-xjc-parsing-fails-when-binding-is-used-together-with-catalog-bug)) and overall I have the impression that this technology is not very solid, when it comes to complex schemas.

So, are there any resources or libraries I should look into to help be build SOAP services by writing and reading XML content directly on the HTTP connection? Currently I am just calling `write` on a `java.net.URLConnection` like:

```
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept"          , "text/xml, multipart/related");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type"    , "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Host"            , url.getHost());
    connection.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Connection", "keep-alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length"  , String.valueOf(postContent.length()));
    OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
    output.write(postContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need something "low level" (but not as extreme as writing the messages as strings) have a look at [SAAJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP_with_Attachments_API_for_Java).

Reference implementation is [here](https://saaj.java.net/) and you can find a starting tutorial in [The Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhr.html).